# WebStorm: using Emmet to quickly convert px to em

Tags: css, webstorm, emmet

Can't figure out how to do an inline calculation to quickly convert `px` to `em` when using WebStorm 11 IDE. (Mac OSX 10.11.3)

For example, within a css file:

**`mb24/16`**

with Emmet, and when using Sublime Text 3, you can press <kbd>Command + Shift + Y</kbd> and it will quickly do the inline calculation:

**`mb24/16`** then becomes **`mb1.5`**

I've been trying to figure out how to do this in WebStorm, but for the life of me I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's not supported.

I found an open issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10679 regarding this feature. You can try your best and vote for it, but i doubt they're gonna implement this anytime soon.